# Call all div's with same ID but different numbers included in that ID

Tags: jquery, html

How can I call all divs that are having the same ID but always a different number appending to that ID, let's say

```
    <div id="divbox-1"></div>
    <div id="divbox-2"></div>
    <div id="divbox-3"></div>
    <div id="divbox-4"></div>
```

and I want to call them through jQuery by clicking on a button

```
    $('#customButton').on("click", function(){
        ...
    });
```

Thanks in advance for your help, I appreciate it alot.

Comment: Why not use a class on those divs?

Comment: Because I am calling dropdown menus from different insertions of a database and on body click I want to close all of them

Comment: @J.Ano that's okay though -- you can still use a class and just separate the logic of the insertion and the click to close. So you could have a special class `js-close-dropdown` and add the event listener on that.

Comment: I'm not certain why that precludes using a class selector to select all of the divs. Could you explain further?

Comment: You said: _I want to call them through jQuery by clicking on a button_
What do you want to do with divs ?

Comment: Look, there are insertions from the database. Many divs, which include dropdown menus. If I click the button to toggle the dropdown menu for a certain insertion, I want the others to close (in case there is any other open dropdown menu). Got it to working already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select them with the [starts with attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (`[name^=”value”]`):

```
$( "[id^='divbox-']" )
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. I appreciate your effort

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="divbox-1" class="weee"></div>
<div id="divbox-2" class="weee"></div>
<div id="divbox-3" class="weee"></div>
<div id="divbox-4" class="weee"></div>

$('#customButton').on("click", function(){
   $('.weee').each(function(i, obj) {
//whatever you want
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As said @j08691, you can use the starts with attribute selector:

```
$("id^='divbox-']").on("click", function(){
    ...
});
```

But it's preferable to use the same class name in your divs, then you get the id of the clicked element and process depending on this id:

```
$(".divbox").on("click", function(e){
     $current_element = $(e.target);
     var id = $current_element.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id^="divbox-"]').on('click', function () {

});
```